# Chitika Ads do not show on page

Tags: php, json, ads

On my site https://www.tvsrbija.online/index.php I have 2 blocks od 728x90 ad and one block of 300x250. Unfortunately these ads are not showing unless they are accessed directly.

https://www.tvsrbija.online/horiz-ad.php (728x90 ad)
https://www.tvsrbija.online/kocka-ad.php (300x250 ad).

As you can see, ads shows just fine when there is not other code on the page.

Note: on https://www.tvsrbija.online/index.php ads are included using php

```
                    <? require('kocka-ad.php'); ?>
```

and

```
                    <? require('horiz-ad.php'); ?>
```

I hope someone can help me troubleshoot this problem.

Also this messages I'm getting in console when visiting my homepage

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
https://mm.chitika.net/minimall?output=jsonp&publisher=lukapaunovic&unit_id…snip_title=Srpski%20TV%20Kanali%20%3A%3A%20U%C5%BEivo%20%7C%20Po%C4%8Detna Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
https://mm.chitika.net/minimall?output=jsonp&publisher=lukapaunovic&unit_id…snip_title=Srpski%20TV%20Kanali%20%3A%3A%20U%C5%BEivo%20%7C%20Po%C4%8Detna Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

**UPDATE:** When i removed

```
            <title>Srpski TV Kanali :: Uživo | %TITLE%</title>
```

ads are showing, i do not understand why. Anyone?

Comment: You need to ask their technical support.

Comment: Problem is on my side, when i remove header ads show, so something is wrong in the code.

Comment: clearly <head> is the problem, i commented it and ads show, fonts or css? possible?

Comment: when i remove   <title>Srpski TV Kanali :: Uživo | %TITLE%</title>
ads are showing, what that means? :O
Really strange